# What does the solid phase in a two-dimensional system with Lennard-Jones potential look like?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, simulations

Consider a system of two dimensional particles interacting via Lennard-Jones pair potential:
$$u(r) = 4[(\frac{1}{r^{12}})-(\frac{1}{r^{6}})]$$ where r is the distance between two particles.
What does the solid phase** look like? Is it a lattice of triangles? Of squares? Is there more than one solid phase? At what pressure/density/temperature do we get a solid phase?

** When I say solid phase I mean a soft solid phase, something that resembles a crystal.

Comment: The most stable/highest density structure is hcp.  But other structures can arise depending on the temp/pressure, including a simple cubic phase at low enough temperatures. A quick google will turn up the phase diagram for a 2D LJ fluid, e.g. [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157381900995).

Comment: I can't find where they say that there could be a cubic phase. can you point me to the relevant page?

Comment: I don't believe it says so in that paper, but the simple cubic phase is metastable so if you construct it and run at a low enough temperature, it will be stable. I don't know whether it would ever be the thermodynamically preferred structure though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a solid phase in two dimensions, as the latter would break translational symmetry and thus violate the Mermin-Wagner theorem.

Rigorous proofs of this fact can be found in the following papers:

- [*On the absence of spontaneous symmetry breaking and of crystalline ordering in two-dimensional systems*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103920246), J. Fröhlich and C. Pfister, Comm. Math. Phys. 81(2) (1981), 277-298.
- [*Translation-Invariance of Two-Dimensional Gibbsian Point Processes*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3637), T. Richthammer, Comm. Math. Phys. 274(1) (2007), 81-122.

Both papers deal with very general interactions (not only Lennard-Jones); the second one even allow for additional hard-core interactions (which are tricky to deal with, from a Mermin-Wagner perspective).

Of course, you might then inquire what *ground-states* look like, but the latter would not be stable at positive temperatures. Rigorous results about the ground states of systems with a class of interactions resembling Lennard-Jones can be found in the paper

- [*A Proof of Crystallization in Two Dimensions*](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfk/Crystallization.pdf), F. Theil, Comm. Math. Phys. 262(1) (2006), 209-236.

It is proved there that, under suitable assumptions on the boundary conditions, the ground state indeed forms a triangular lattice. Even for ground-states in two dimensions, the problem seems still not fully understood. There is also the following nice (and recent) review paper on this topic:

- [*The crystallization conjecture: a review*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01153),  X. Blanc and M. Lewin, EMS Surveys in Mathematical Sciences 2(2) (2015), 255-306.

Comment: Excellent references for the absence of long-ranged crystalline order in 2D.  However,  a certain kind of solid phase is possible in 2D with quasi long-ranged order.  See  http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4094

Comment: @Couchyam : Sure, I agree with you: they are the analogues of the massless phase in $O(N)$ models. However they are not considered to be solid phases (the latter are characterized by the breaking of translation invariance), and I doubt that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: so how did people get solid in 2D lennard jonse? I believe the mermin wagner work only when the  potential is short ranged. maybe this is the problem. an article with solid simulation: ac.els-cdn.com/0370157381900995/1-s2.0-0370157381900995-main.pdf?_tid=add2a556-ef43-11e5-ba12-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1458551146_88b013c35f7fb17cc656be144e4784cf

Comment: @AdiRo : of course not. The proofs in the papers I link to apply just as well to interactions of infinite range. In particular, they apply to Lennard-Jones interactions. In two dimensions, you do not see true solid phases, in the sense that there cannot be positional long-range order. What is possible, however, is to have some kind of "soft crystal" phases, which look like solid *locally*; this is due to the very slow deformations of the crystal over long distances. All this is completely analogous to the massless (Kosterlitz-Thouless) phase in the 2d XY model.

Comment: @AdiRo: This is even discussed *explicitly* in the paper you refer to: just read Sections 2 and 3. What the author does is to argue that a *new* definition of a solid phase is needed. But there is no discussion (it is a mathematical fact) that in two dimensions translation invariance cannot be broken.

Comment: @AdiRo : He is actually taking a pragmatic position: in *finite* systems, you *see* something that looks like a solid phase, so let's call that a solid phase! That might seem reasonable, but is actually conceptually a bad idea: with such a point of view, you can have long-range order in the one-dimensional Ising model, for example! Indeed, for finite systems and sufficiently low temperatures (depending on the system's size), you get a magnetized sample.

Comment: @AdiRo : Using precise definitions for the concepts one uses is very important. There are very good reasons for defining them using the thermodynamic limit. Then, of course, one should also say what happens in finite ("real") systems.  In particular, these "soft-crystal" phases can and must be studied: they are very interesting and more tractable than the 3d solid phases. However,  they should not be called *solid*.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Ok so let me rephrase. I am looking at a finite system, with periodic boundary conditions. when I said solid I meant "soft solid". and thank you for the important distinction